# Primes from the given set

Tags: prime-numbers

If we are given a set of positive integers and asked to find the prime numbers from this set considering the divisor must belong to this set only, Is there any way apart from dividing  every number with other to do this.
for e.g- the set is{10,8,3,5,4,34} so the primes are 3,5,4 and 34.

Comment: You want something like Sieve of Eratosthenes ?